# Add text AFTER Activities button

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-panel

I would like to know how to add text after the activities button on the top bar.  I already know how to change the Activities button text with a shell extension, but I want to add text after it, that does nothing.  With the `Unite` shell extension, you can add text when the desktop is focused, and that helps a little, but I would like that to be shown all the time, and not just on the desktop.  I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME 3.36.2.

Comment: I have surfed the files, and haven't found a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may achieve this by creating a `gnome-shell extension`

Extension UUID: `add_plain_text_beside_actv_button@username.domain` Change this in below command (and further) if you wish to have other name.. Other wise just copy paste the below command and run.

run

```
install -D /dev/null $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/add_plain_text_beside_actv_button@username.domain@username.domain/extension.js
```

run

```
install -D /dev/null $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/add_plain_text_beside_actv_button@username.domain@username.domain/metadata.json
```

copy paste the below content in `extension.js` file and change "Your Text Here" at line no. 12, in the below content with whatever text you need.

```
'use strict';

const { St, Clutter } = imports.gi;

const Main = imports.ui.main;

let _myText;

class Extension {

    enable() {
    _myText = new St.Label({ text: 'Your Text Here', y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER, style_class: 'panel-button', track_hover: true, reactive: true });
    Main.panel._leftBox.insert_child_at_index(_myText, 1)
    }

    disable() {
    _myText.destroy();
    }
}

function init() {
    return new Extension();
}
```

copy paste the below content in `metadata.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "Add Plain Text Beside Activities Button",
  "description": "Add Plain Beside After Activities Button",
  "uuid": "add_plain_text_beside_actv_button@username.domain",
  "shell-version": [
    "3.36"
  ]
}
```

Save the files & close..

If you are on Xorg session. you can refresh the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r Enter method and then turn on the extension.

If you are on Wayland session. logout and login and then turn on the extension.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This did not work.  In my extensions list, the enable switch is grayed out.  Is there some command I can run to see the error? (also thank you for the detail in your answer)

Comment: Yes, I have the activities button hidden.  This should not effect it though, because this should add text after the button.

Comment: For some reason, I can't see it in my extensions list now.

Comment: may be you have not edited `metadata.json` file. check the extensions folder name and UUID line in `metadata.json` file. extension folder name and uuid both should be `add_plain_text_beside_actv_button@username.domain`

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: One more thing, how would I set the font weight on this?